# .htaccess 301 редирект для страниц с параметрами

Tags: .htaccess

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться.

на страницы типа

> site.com/?abrakadabra
>
> site.com/articles?abrakadabra
>
> site.com/galleries/arbors?sgfds

сервер дает ответ 200 и создались дубли страниц в индексе гугл
нужно правильно сделать 301 переадресацию с страниц

> site.com/?abrakadabra на site.com
>
> site.com/articles?ljuboj_tekst на site.com/articles

прописывал так

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^\?]+)\? $1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L,R=permanent]
```

и так

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

и так

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [l,r=301]
```

в результате зациклена переадресация.

возможно какая-то ошибка или я что-то неправильно делаю.
Файл htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.host.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://host.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^(.*)\.tpl$ [R=404]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.zip$ [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 !^(index\.php|user_guide|uploads/.*|favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|captcha/.*|application/modules/.*/templates|application/modules/.*/assets/js|application/modules/.*/assets/css|application/modules/.*/assets/images|CHANGELOG.xml|templates|js|robots\.txt|mpdf)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php?/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: оно и xас адресуется, как вы хотите. предлагаете убить query?  а как вы будете узнавать про абракадабру и любой текст?

Comment: я только учусь и с этим не сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста какое решение данной проблемы?